# Python on heroku gives h12

Tags: python, heroku, npm

I coded an api Nodejs with python fecthing data and making some plots to pdf file. It' just simple api works with 100-200 datarow in pandas.

So It works fine in my local machine but when I push it to heroku(free tier) it gives h12 timeout error.How can I improve my api speed, is there a way to python build or npm built to make production version of the api.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there  anyway to make it faster or gain more time then 30 sec

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the hardest things in `Heroku`. Usually, `Heroku` will give you time out after the `30s`. But there is a lot of work around according to your type of app.

**1. `Flask` and streaming response**

> `Heroku` will give a timeout error if your app returns nothing in the `30s`. So you can stream your response while processing is the one way to overcome this error. For more details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272072/flask-send-stream-as-response) and [here](https://librenepal.com/article/flask-and-heroku-timeout/).

**2. Run your long process in the background**

> Another way to bypass this time out error is, you can send the longest time taking process to the background task list there is no time limit in the background task. You can see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) more about it

**3. Change timeout in `gunicorn`**

> If you are using `gunicorn` and `Flask` you can bypass the error with the trick refer the gunicorn document [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html). Still, you cannot set the timeout larger than the `30s` but you can terminate the process less than the 30s without error and you can re-run

**I think in your case streaming response will do the job. Just iterate through each row and stream response after every row processed.**